# Initialize a nested data frame in R

Tags: r, initialization, nested, data.table

I have a nested data table called ldt. The highest dimension in each direction is

```
ldt[[44]][7200,4]
```

Meaning each nested data.table (DT) is 7200 rows by 4 columns, and there are 44 such nested DTs.

I want to create a second set of DTs based on the first.

Specifically, I want to execute the command

```
for (i in length(ldt)) {ldtSUM[[i]]<-ldt[[i]][, sum(V4), by="V1,V3"]}
```

If successful, this should generate a nested array of dimensionality

```
ldtSUM[[44]][120,4]
```

but instead doing so results in the error:

```
Error in ldtSUM[[i]] <- ldt[[i]][, sum(V4), by = "V1,V3"] : object 'ldtSUM' not found
```

presumably because I never initialized it.

So, to circumvent this, I attempted a variety of initialization techniques such as

```
ldtSUM=ldt[[1:44]][0,]
```

and many other statements, but they all failed for a variety of reasons, such as that I did not specify a number of empty rows, or "recursive indexing failed at level 3" etc.

So, in summary, what I would like to do is create a data.table wherein $V4 is summed by $V1,$V3 but I cannot seem to do this due to indexing and initialization issues.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Avoid `for` loop. Use something like `lapply(ldt,function(x)x[, sum(V4), by = "V1,V3"])`.

Comment: Thank you! I began by experimenting lapply syntax but abandoned this.
This is what I originally should have gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on agstudy's answer, the correct code is:

```
ldtSUM<-lapply(ldt,function(x)x[, sum(V4), by = "V1,V3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You had two parts to your problem:
The first part you have already solved by:

```
ldtSUM<-lapply(ldt,function(x)x[, sum(V4), by = "V1,V3"]
```

The second part is on initialization, and that can be solved by following:

```
ldtSUM <- list()
```

After this initialization if you run your original code:

```
for (i in length(ldt)) {ldtSUM[[i]]<-ldt[[i]][, sum(V4), by="V1,V3"]}
```

should also work.

Note: For your problem, the solution suggested by agstudy is best. But the initialization is a general trick that is useful in variety of situations.